# How to set the -D java option in Eclipse IDE?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have to start a program that need the -D option like:
-Dproperty=path
But where I can set this in Eclipse IDE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right click on your main class or project in eclipse --> Run As --> Run Configurations --> Select your main class's "run configuration" on the left side of the opened window.

Please take a look on the attached print screen

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In RunConfigurations->[YourRunConfiguration]->Arguments->VM arguments

Answer (score 0):

You can right click on the project and in the pop menu you have an option `Run as...` resp. `Debug As...` On this menu you can create runtime configurations and there you can also add the switches that should be passed to the java environment. `VM Arguments`